# How to export NetBeans Platform Application using Maven to an executable installer?

Tags: maven, netbeans, installation, executable-jar, netbeans-platform

Update: I have found the solution and it is posted below. Original question: "How to export NetBeans Platform Application using Maven to an executable JAR?"

I am new to desktop application development and I started learning about the NetBeans platform.

I followed this tutorial on the NetBeans website: [NetBeans Platform CRUD Tutorial Using Maven](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-crud.html)

The question is how do I export the completed project into an executable JAR file? There is actually 3 projects; the -app, -parent, -branding, + any additional modules you have. How do I package everything including the Java DB file into a single JAR file for easy distribution? There are instructions on how to do this using Ant, but no one has asked this question regarding Maven.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution and I am posting it here to help noobs like me in the future.

1. Right click the -app project>properties

   [image]
2. Under build>installer, select the installers you want

   [image]
3. Under actions, create a new custom action and call it whatever you want. I called it "Generate installers". Enter "nbm:build-installers" under execute goals.

   [image]
4. Right click the project>custom>Generate installers

   [image]
5. When it's done, the installer.exe file will appear under the -app/target folder

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no way, not even for Ant base Netbeans module projects. Maybe you confused it with Ant j2se projects? A lot of functionality would break IMHO, update center, even module classloading etc.

The -app project creates a zip file (or platform native installers) that contains the application in the proper structure. That's how you distribute the application.

Comment: Wait, so I'm supposed to just distribute that .zip file in my -app/target folder? How do I make NetBeans generate installers so it's easier for less technically inclined users to use the application?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've found and posted the solution below.